# Remove "X-Powered-By: Nuxt" from Nuxt 3 Response Headers

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I just upgraded to the official release of Nuxt 3 and updated my server middleware to the following. However, anything I try does not remove or overwrite the default "x-powered-by" header. I'd like to change it to something else. It always says `x-powered-by: Nuxt`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  event.node.res.removeHeader('x-powered-by') // Does not remove the header 
  event.node.res.setHeader('x-powered-by', 'Something Else') // Does not overwrite header
})
```

This used to work, but this method has been deprecated:

```js
import type { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http'

export default async (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => {
  res.setHeader('x-powered-by', 'Something Else')
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to remove the "X-Powered-By" header using the [`render:response`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/advanced/hooks#nitro-app-hooks-runtime-server-side) nitro hook, via server plugin:
/server/plugins/nitroPlugin.ts

```js
import {RenderResponse} from "nitropack";

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
    nitroApp.hooks.hook('render:response', (response: RenderResponse) => {
        delete response.headers['X-Powered-By'];
    })
})
```

Comment: from [nuxt >= 3.1.0](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/c552d1b420caaac0184fd5c332ebc55b0b0d77ad/packages/nuxt/src/core/runtime/nitro/renderer.ts#L336) the header key is in lowercase, so use `'x-powered-by'` instead.